# Error in 2^I : non-numeric argument to binary operator - Rcapture package

Tags: r

I'm using the Rcapture package and I'm getting this error:

Error in 2^I : non-numeric argument to binary operator

My code is:

```
library(Rcapture)

captura <- read.csv("~/Desktop/Rcapture.csv", header = TRUE)

View(captura)

openp(captura, dfreq = FALSE, m = c("ep"), neg = TRUE, keep = rep(TRUE, 2^I-1))
```

This is what the Rcapture cran r project says about the "keep" argument:

"This option is useful to fit the model on a subset of the possible capture histories.keep is a logical vector of length 2
I − 1 taking the value TRUE for a history kept and FALSE for a history put aside. In this vector, the order of the capture
histories is as defined in the histpos.t function. By default, every capture history is kept."

Comment: What is the value of `I`? The error message says it is non-numeric.

Comment: `I` is a base function. Choose another name for that variable and post reproducible code and data. Can you post the output of `dput(head(captura, 20))` in the question?